# Android find fragment returns null always

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity within it I do

```
    FragmentTransaction trans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    FragmentList fragList = new FragmentList();
    trans.replace(R.id.fragList, fragList, "fragList");
```

to fill my frame layout with the actual fragment. That works fine. Through navigation I end up later in some other activity and some other fragment. In that new fragment I have to call a method of my list fragment to tell it that something has changed.

```
FragmentList listfrag = (FragmentList) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragList");
FragmentList listfrag2 = (FragmentList) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fraglist); 
listfrag.updateData(b);
```

Both, listfrag and listfrag2, are always null. Why?

Edit:

based on the answer that this is not possible from one activity to another activity. I have activity A,
On a tablet A has fragment F1 and F2, on a phone only F1. If I select something on F1, the either F2 gets updated or activity B is called to show F2. In F2 I press a save button and I want to update F1 based. So I either have to call something in the same activity (tablet) or in different acitivty (phone). How can I do this without duplicating my code for the updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getFragmentManager()` method gets a reference to the `FragmentManager` that is used within *that activity*.

In essence, you are creating the Fragment in one Activity, but looking for it in another. You can't do that (easily).

It sounds like you might want to use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` to pass data back and forth between the Activities.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment lifecycle is tied to its activity, you can't call it from another activity. But in the same activity when you replace with another fragment,

Try this,

```
trans
     .replace(R.id.fragList, fragList, "fragList")
     .addToBackStack(null) // this will keep fragment when you replace with another.
     .commit();
```